# Please help me de-cipher this line of bash scripting code

Tags: bash, resty

What does this mean?

```
  h2t=$((exec 2>&-; (which lynx >/dev/null && echo lynx -stdin -dump) \
            || which html2text || which cat) |tail -n 1)
```

Ok, `h2t=...` means it's setting a variable.

I thought double-parens were for arithmetic operations.  If that's the case I don't see any arithmetic there, and I'm thoroughly baffled.

Of course, there is a 15-line comment block above that line of code, which explains the intent. Unfortunately the comment is in unicode version of ancient sumerian, and I cannot interpret it.

**Only kidding!  There is no comment.

Addendum: This is from https://github.com/micha/resty/blob/master/resty

Comment: Does it really say `$((`?

Comment: yes - please see https://github.com/micha/resty/blob/master/resty for the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) in a comment to my answer spotted it. Turns out the outer `$()` assigns a command line, depending on the availability of various tools that might be able to convert HTML to text.

Therefore `h2t` contains either the `lynx -stdin -dump` command line, or failing that (i.e. `lynx` not available), `html2text` or as a last resort `cat`. The commands for the latter two come from the `which` invocations, the one for the former from the `echo`.

---

It converts HTML to text from stdin.

Let's split it up.

- `exec 2>&-` sets up a redirect in the subshell (shuts up `stderr`, IIRC)
- the next sub-subshell tries to see whether lynx is installed and runs it, taking input from `stdin`.
- the other parts after the `||` make not much sense because they only evaluate whether `html2text` and `cat` are installed, but don't run them
- then we fetch the last line from that first subshell

**Scratch that.** Since it's an `echo` it doesn't do anything. Looks like prototyping to me.

Taking it apart to make more readable:

```
$(
    exec 2>&-
      (
        which lynx >/dev/null &&
        echo lynx -stdin -dump
      ) ||
    which html2text ||
    which cat
  ) |
  tail -n 1
)
```

Comment: Actually, it only assigns to a variable a more-or-less suitable command line whose intent is to convert from html to text... If either `lynx` or `html2text` are available, the variable will contain an appropriate command line featuring that tool, otherwise, it falls back to a default of `cat`.

Comment: @twalberg: good catch, you're right. Edited it into my answer. Leaving the rest intact. Let me know if you decide to write up your own, so I'll delete mine.

Comment: ok, so it's choosing an html2text program to run, hence the name of the var `h2t`.  It isn't running it. It's just finding it, and failing lynx or html2text, chooses cat. If you actually put this in your answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Thanks, @0xC0000022L, I've accepted it.  "The application failed to initialize properly"?

Comment: @Cheeso: you mean `0xC0000022L`? -> `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` ... most people shortened this to `SAD` which annoyed me mightily ;)

Comment: ah - I see. I don't have my Windows machine anymore and cannot grep winerr.h.  I resorted to the google and it failed me.  anyway, cool username.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the exact rule for disambiguating the syntax, but it should be parsed like this:

```
h2t=$(
       (exec 2>&-; (which lynx >/dev/null && echo lynx -stdin -dump) ||
         which html2text ||
         which cat) |
       tail -n 1
     )
```

In other words, a command substitution consisting of a subshell piped into `tail`. The subshell is used to provide a "scope" for the `exec` command, after which another subshell starts a list whose 3 commands are separated by the `||` operator.